# What are some must-know trig identities?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, proof-explanation

I'm having a hard time with trigonometry. Not in the sense that I can't solve problems, but that I don't understand what I'm using. I see a trig identity and just sort of accept that it works without necessarily seeing how it was derived. But most of the time when I see the equivalence I have no idea how they got there.

Are there a few "core" identities from which the rest can be derived? Or am I barking up the wrong tree and just need to suck it up and memorize?

Comment: Remember $\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x)=1$ then everything can be derived from there

Comment: I'd add $\sin(x+y)=\sin x\cos y+\cos x\sin y$, $\cos(x+y)=\cos x\cos y-\sin x\sin y$ and $\cos x=\sin(\pi/2-x)$.

Comment: All trig identities can be derived using complex analysis. Do you have background in this subject?

Comment: Actually I have to admit $\sin(x\pm y)$ and $\cos(x\pm y)$ I always had a hard time remembering.  Until  I thought in terms of complex analysis.  $(\cos x + i\sin x)(\cos y + i \sin y) = \cos (x+y) + i\sin(x+y) \implies (\cos x\cos y - \sin x\sin y) + i(\sin x\cos y +\cos x\sin y) = \cos (x+y) + i\sin(x+y) $ made the whole thing very easy to remember.

Comment: The rest $\sin (x + \pi) = -\sin x$ etc. All make perfect sense be just imagining the unit circle and rotating and flipping it accordingly.

Comment: @fleablood Can you explain the complex analysis bit a little more?

Comment: A non-zero complex number has an angle, and a size.  To multiply two complex numbers, you add the angles and multiply this sizes.  So if $z = \cos x + i \sin x$ and $w = \cos y + i \sin y$, then $xy = \cos (x + y) + i \sin (x+y)$.  So $\cos (x+y) = \cos x *\cos y - \sin x \sin y$ and $\sin(x + y) = \sin x\cos y + \cos x \sin y$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Learn and remember the basic geometric definition of trigonometric functions, notably

- $\cos x$ and $\sin x$ are the coordinates of the point M on the
  trigonometric circle
- $\tan x$ is the y coordinate of the intersection between the vertical
  line from (1,0) and the line OM
- ...

and so on.

[image]

From here the foundamental relationships

- $\sin^2 \theta + \cos^2 \theta =1$
- $\tan \theta=\frac{\sin \theta}{\cos \theta}$
- ...

and so on.

The basic values for the basic angles for all trigonometric functions. Note that it suffice to memorize the important values in the first quadrant/octant and then obtain the others by symmetry and basic trigonometric identities.

[image]

Refer to the wiki [List of trigonometric identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities) as summary.

Answer (score 2):

1) Learn the definitions of $$sin(x), cos(x), tan(x), cot(x),...$$
2) Learn basic relation between these functions, such as $$sin^2(x)+cos^2(x)=1, sec^2(x) = 1+ tan^2(x),...$$ 
3) Learn addition formulas such as $$sin(a+b)=sin(a)cos(b)+cos(a)sin(b),...$$
4) Learn double angle formulas, such as $$sin(2a) = 2sin(a)cos(a),....$$
5) learn trig functions of $ \pi$ , $\pi /2,$, $ \pi /6,$.....

Comment: Where does $\sin(a+b)$ come from?

Comment: To the proposer: There are many ways to prove the angle-sum formulas for \sin (a+b) and \cos (a+b) but I wouldn't call it an obvious result. There is a brief simple proof in the old classic textbook Trigonometry by Hobson.